# CUDA accessing device memory directly

Tags: memory, cuda

Can I access device memory directly somehow? E.g.

```
float* vector;
cudaMalloc(vector, sizeof(float)*100);
vector[53] = 2.345;
cudaFree(vector);
```

I can write ugly kernel for doing such thing, but it is very bad decision.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA 6 introduced Unified Memory which allows you to perform this type of operation. All you need to do is change your cudaMalloc call to cudaMallocManaged and you should be able to access the memory from both the GPU and CPU without explicitly calling cudaMemcpy or launching a kernel.

```
float* vector;
cudaMallocManaged(&vector, sizeof(float)*100);
vector[53] = 2.345;
cudaFree(vector);
```

One thing to note is that this is only supported on the newer NVIDIA cards(sm_30 and up) and only works on 64-bit Windows and Linux operating systems. Also depending on your system and your usage, this type of access might not be as efficient as traditional cudaMemcpy or cudaMemset functions

Comment: Ha ha, of course, Unified Memory is anything but direct in giving access to the memory. It just hides the data copying. The platform supports mapping of device memory into the CPU address space, NVIDIA has just chosen not to expose that capability for various reasons.